# MySQL - Difference between two statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I noticed this SQL query in a documentation:

```
UPDATE pages page
LEFT JOIN pages parentpage ON page.pid = parentpage.uid
LEFT JOIN pages grandparentpage ON parentpage.pid = grandparentpage.uid
LEFT JOIN pages grandgrandparentpage ON grandparentpage.pid = grandgrandparentpage.uid
SET page.is_hidden = 0
WHERE page.uid = 5
OR page.pid = 5
OR parentpage.pid = 5
OR grandparentpage.pid = 5
OR grandgrandparentpage.pid = 5;
```

Isn't this exactly the same as:

```
UPDATE pages page
SET page.is_hidden = 0
WHERE page.uid = 5
OR page.pid = 5;
```

PID and UID are filtered by the where clause to equal 5. Therefore I don't see, why this JOINs would be important.

But maybe I am missing the point?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE is a strange thing to behold

Comment: *Isn't this exactly the same as* No. Create 4 chained rows where only `grandgrandparentpage.pid = 5` and compare the results for these queries. 1st query will update all rows whereas 2nd only 2 rows.

Comment: @Strawberry Why not? Imagine there is only one row with `uid = 5`, and it must be (un)marked hidden. Only mostleft table is updated...

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with data that is hierarchical in nature. I would take extra caution with modifying any existing documentation. The 2 update statements are not the same. The first uses left joins to mimic the child parent relationship for the update

Comment: Explain in detail referencing authoritative documentationl why you expect what you expect or we can't address your misconceptions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @Akina I'm struggling to picture that.

Comment: To make this clear. This is the exact query, I have got from documentation, parent and so on are no placeholders, they indeed do it that way. Maybe Akina's answer points to the right direction, however, I'm still struggling to understand it.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: If you don't say why you think they are the same then you will be posting an endless series of "but" comments on an endless series of "answers" that give correct reasoning that just doesn't happen to hit your misconception. They are different because that is how the language is defined. Say why you think they are the same. If you can't then you have no reason to think that you have an opinion on whether they are the same so why do you?  (You will also probably find your own misconceptions while finding your first unexpected subexpression result while constructing your *obligatory* [mre].)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q9yQkDEpvN1rSNg93rYc29/1). The first SQL will up date not only the row with `uid` 5 but also its child, grandchild and great-grandchild if they exist.

Comment: But here, the table is joined with itself. They call it parent, grandparent etc. but they always use the pages table. Isn't everything contained in the pages table already covered by the first select (pages page)?

pages page => Page table with placeholder name page
pages parent => Page table with placeholder name parent

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Imagine you had 4 identical tables (clones of one another with duplicated rows) named `page`, `parentpage`, `grandparentpage` and `grandgrandparentpage` on which the joins were being performed. What would the results be? The actual SQL is equivalent to that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

They are different, because the first query updates all children, grandchildren and grandgrandchildren rows of a `pid=5` or `uid=5` row. The second will update only the rows themselves.

Here's an example how the queries are different:

```
|uid|pid| first query                 | second query     |
| 1 | 5 | Yes, page.pid=5             | Yes. page.pid=5  |
| 5 | 6 | Yes, page.uid=5             | Yes. page.uid=5  |
| 6 | 7 | Yes, parentpage.pid=5       | No               |
| 7 | 8 | Yes, grapdppage.pid=5       | No               |
| 8 | 9 | Yes, grandgrandppage.pid=5  | No               |
| 9 | 10| No                          | No               |
```

Comment: But parentpage, grandparentpage etc. are taken from the same table (pages). Aren't they already covered by pages page (because pages parentpage is still pages table)? I have to clarify the this is a real example I got. Those aren't placeholder I included. In my opinion, if parentpage grandparentpage etc. are just aliases (aren't they?), everything is already covered by the second statement (or, like I was asking, I'm (still) missing it)...

Comment: Nope. This structure is called hierarchy. One condition only covers one level, so the first query returns 5 levels while thes second returns only 2. Neither returns infinite deep. Try it out!